# CSS sprites and gradients

Tags: css-sprites

Is it possible to put multiple repeating gradients on a single sprite master image? I've got about 5 1px X 400 px gradients that could be combined to reduce the page requests. It's pretty much my last place to go for reducing object requests. I haven't seen any techniques for this while searching. My own experimentation hasn't had good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the areas you're applying the background gradients to are less than 400px high, you can tile the five sprites vertically to give you a single 1x4000px image.

You could apply the appropriate part of the sprite by specifying a vertical offset, and setting `background-repeat:repeat-x`.

The vertical offset would be `400 * (index of the sprite you want)`: `0px` for the first, `400px` for the 2nd, `800px` for the 3rd, etc.

Comment: Here is my without any critical thinking immediate response. Will this work with sprites of odd widths as well?

Comment: All the sprites have to be the same width, otherwise you'll have strips of blank space between them when they're repeated.  This shouldn't be a problem if the sprites are meant to tile horizontally anyways...

Comment: I was thinking about using radial gradients, but I guess they will have to be linear. So, really, you can get away with three sprites overall - all your static background images, a sprite for vertical linear gradients, and a sprite for horizontal linear gradients. Way cool. Thanks.